# Email is not being send?

Tags: apex

```
<apex:page id="forgotPassword" showHeader="false" controller="ForgotPasswordController1" title="{!$Label.site.forgot_password}">
<apex:composition template="{!$Site.Template}">
<apex:define name="body">

<apex:form id="theForm">
<apex:pageMessages id="error"/>

<h2>Reset your password</h2>
<p>Forgot your password? Enter your email address below to send you a temprary password.</p>
<br/>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-4">
      <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Forgot Password</strong></h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
              <form role="form">
                  <fieldset>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="username">Username</label>
                          <apex:inputText required="true" styleClass="form-control" id="username" value="{!username}"/>
                      </div>
                      <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                      <apex:commandButton id="submit" value="Reset Password" action="{!forgotPassword}" styleClass="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block" />
                  </fieldset>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

</apex:form>                  
</apex:define>
</apex:composition>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
/**
 * An apex page controller that exposes the site forgot password functionality
 */
public with sharing class ForgotPasswordController1{
    public String username {get; set;}   

    public ForgotPasswordController1() {}

    public PageReference forgotPassword() {
      boolean success = Site.forgotPassword(username);
      PageReference pr = Page.ForgotPasswordConfirm;
      pr.setRedirect(success);
      system.debug('Username is ----------'+username);
      system.debug('Boolean value is '+ success );
      system.debug('THis is the page it is redirecting--->'+pr);


      if (success) {        
        return pr;
      }
      return null;
    }
}
```

I used above code But it is not sending the mail to email id . How can I achieve this?

Comment: Post your controller code also

Comment: @two things are you running this page in Site or Community? if no then this will only work with Site or Community. Second If you are in SB then check your email delivery settings and check it must be all emails.

Answer (score 0):

The site was not active thats why the email was not going ! Thanks man!

Comment: Guys, this answer is from the OP (and the only answer). I'm going to dismiss these review flags. That being said, Syed, you might want to have a quick read of the [help] and [ask] and [answer]. Your question will be less likely to get flagged for deletion if you fill out a little more detail about how you resolved your problem. What were the specific steps you took in investigation and resolution?